# Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip Popover display issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

Im attempting to use both bootstrap Popover and Tooltip. Tooltip displays correctly as a hover until the popover is clicked which appears momenterly before disapearing at which point the tooltip stops working.

This is using Ruby-on-Rails 4 if that makes any difference.

Application.js:

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-tooltip
//= require bootstrap-popover

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip({ placement : 'right' });
  $('[rel=popover]').popover();
});
```

vew:

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="first tooltip">
  <i class="icon-question-sign"></i>
</a>

<a href="#" rel="popover" data-original-title="first popover" data-content="this is some popover data">
  <i class="icon-question-sign"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: jsfiddle will better explain your situation?

Comment: jsfiddle + giving us browser version and name.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a Rails 4 issue with turbolinks resolved it by changing the JavaScript to:

```
var ready = function () {
$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip({ placement : 'right',
                           container: 'body' });
$('[rel=popover]').popover();
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```